# HTML offline map with local tiles via Leaflet

Tags: html, maps, leaflet, offline, tiles

Is there a way to display a map for a given area completely offline using HTML and JavaScript? I am looking for a mobile-friendly (read Cordova-enabled) solution.

Answer (score 44):

There is an elegant solution for this problem in [this blog post](http://davidrs.com/wp/phonegap-3-0-leaflet-offline-maps/). I have compiled a full code example from it. Here are the steps:

**1. Create map tiles**

- download [Mobile Atlas Creator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mobac/)
- create a new atlas with **OSMdroid ZIP** format
- make map and zoom selection, add your selection to the atlas
- click "Create atlas"
- unzip the atlas file
- your tiles have this format: **{atlas_name}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png** ({z} stands for "zoom")

**2. Set up HTML and JavaScript**

- copy your atlas folder to your HTML root
- download [leaflet.js and leaflet.css](http://leafletjs.com/) and copy them to html root
- create index.html with the code below

  - adjust starting coordinates and zoom on the line where *var mymap* is defined
  - change atlasName to your folder name, set your desired maxZoom

**3. You are all set! Enjoy!**

- run index.html in your browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head> 
  <title>Leaflet offline map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" href="leaflet.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script>
   function onLoad() {

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([50.08748, 14.42132], 16);

    L.tileLayer('atlasName/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {    maxZoom: 16  }).addTo(mymap);
   }
  </script> 
 </head>
 <body onload="onLoad();"> 
  <div id="mapid" style="height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `.svg` instead? Downloading `.png` doesn't seem right.

Answer (score -1):

you should do these steps one by one

1. Download the mbtiles file of the specific area from https://openmaptiles.org/
2. establish the Map Server by Docker
3. implement the web pages by Leaflet.js and use the map server IP address in your codes.

Comment: "establish the Map Server by Docker" LOL

Comment: this answer might not be correct for this particular question. But it kinda helped me. Thanks

Comment: This answer could be worded better but I think running a tile server locally is valid if you want to test the app offline. This wouldn't really work for a packaged and deployable solution though