# Can not show leaflet map offline in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt5, leaflet

In my PyQt app I want to show a leaflet map. The code works fine with online tiles but what I want to do is to show the map offline and for this I have downloaded some tiles for an area using Mobile Atlas Creator, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43608920/14858777) is how to do that. If I open html file in browser the map works fine however it's not working in PyQt app.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        browser = QWebEngineView()
        html = open('index.html', 'r').read()
        browser.setHtml(html)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hBox = QVBoxLayout()
        hBox.addWidget(browser)
        vbox.addLayout(hBox)
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 100vh; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>

    var loc = [48.85628846134472, 2.2929097921857955]
    var map = L.map('map').setView(loc, 16);

    // this work
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    // this dose'nt work
    L.tileLayer('img/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18  }).addTo(map);
   
</script>
```

Comment: Your `index.html` still depends on online CSS files (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>`). Can you download those and use local copies?

Comment: @kwsp Yes I can. But right now it doesn't matter. I just want to show my downloaded tiles

Comment: I see. Notice that `L.tileLayer` takes a URL as a parameter, so you need to pass in the local URL of that PNG file. I'm not familiar with QWebEngineView, but have you looked into how it loads local resources? A starting point might be https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.3/qwebenginenavigationrequest.html

Comment: @kwsp Thank you. It worked! I had to pass the the path like `"file:///D:/path/to/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"`